# can %s be an integer? *Python code*

Tags: python

Looking at this django code from the djangobook:

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
import datetime

def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    try:
        offset = int(offset)
    except ValueError:
        raise Http404()
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

after the try, it converts offset into an integer, right? and in the line 'datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)', offset is used as an integer, but in the line 
'html = "In %s hour(s), it will be %s." % (offset, dt)'

offset is a %s which is a string, right? Or am I miss understanding? I thought %s only can be a string, not an integer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`%s` calls the `str()` method on its corresponding argument... (similar to `%r` calls `repr()`) - so either of those can be used for *any* object... Unlike `%d` (`%i` is the same) and `%f` for instance which will require appropriate types.

Comment: You can find this explicitly stated in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) in the Conversion Table.

Answer (score 1):

If `offset` is an **integer** (in this particular case, it's not true for any object type), then you can use any of `%s`, `%d`, `%r` and you'll get the same result.

`%d` formats an integer number for display, `%s` calls `str()` on an argument, `%r` calls `repr()`:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> str(n)
'5'
>>> repr(n)
'5'
```

Also see [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

In the future, when you're inquisitive about something, fire up the interpreter and explore the simplest case yourself.

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a
1
>>> 'this is %s string.' % (a)
'this is 1 string.'
```

Then extrapolate questions from there.  Maybe next use an arbitrary object, since an int worked where you thought you needed a str:

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> b = Thread()
>>> b
<Thread(Thread-1, initial)>
>>> 'this is %s string.' % (b)
'this is <Thread(Thread-1, initial)> string.'
```

This is the general flow of how I explore unexpected results.  If you're a doc person, go for it, but I personally never been one for reading the manual; I just don't absorb information that way.

Comment: +1 for recommending to just try it.  `'%s' % 1` is all that is needed.